# How to find and delete specific row in blogger css with span tag?

Tags: html, css

My english is not to much good, and i dont know  to describe this problem good.

I have some blog on Blogger and I was install some free theme. I dont want to my name (author info) is on whole blog, but there is no button to check it off, I must do it trough HTML editor.
I found and delete it from most of places on blog, but I cant delete it from some header "slideshow"

I try to find it via "inspect elements" option, to find some familiar word there and search it in html. I know to I cant build web site if I dont know main steps, but I always stuck on some stupid things.

```
<span class="recent-author">Alexandar Sh</span></div>
```

This part make me trouble, maybe I looks stupid, but I am :D . I am total amateur with this and I dont know what to do to I dont get this anymore.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYFHG.png)

One more [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e07B7.png)

This "recent" probably activate this option to work to show slideshow (not moving images <[One more screenshot][3]>) so when I type that "display: none" option, I block all "widget"

Thanks for help!
I got idea (didnt know to that is possible) and add  tag to widget part of code. (before I add this, what you add me, after first Style tag. I didnt see before to there is more style tags. So you help me both. I use tag becouse Rico tell me that, and put code what Derek gave me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have access to a `.css` CSS file. That is the 'Styles' for your site. (`.html` is the markup/content`) etc. ~ If you can find a place that has CSS rules... you could add:

```
.recent-author {
  display: none;
}
```

For reasons I'm not going to try and explain here... you may also need to add this:

```
.recent-author {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line in any of your Css files:

```
span.recent-author {
    display: none;
}
```

If you don't have any Css file / don't have access to any just add an inline style tag in your html file:

```
<style>
   code from above
</style>
```

This should remove your author `span` tag.

Comment: I don't know how this is possible but make sure you wrote everything correctly and that there are no spaces in `span.recent-author`.

Comment: I copy paste your code. I update my first post
and this is screenshot 3
http://i.stack.imgur.com/v1QPY.png